# Photoshop Using the OSX Color Picker

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, osx, glitch

Not sure what happened but Photoshop no longer opens the normal color picker but instead opens the OSX color picker/wheel. I've tried restarting and install the most recent version of Photoshop with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefs  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  > General

Colour picker - you have the choice of Adobe or Apple...

[image]